# Programmatically perform click on a DataGridView Button Cell from another Button

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a question regarding `DataGridView` control in .NET.

I inserted a `DataGridView` from the toolbox and I connected it with a database that I setup in access. Then I added a column with buttons from the edit columns of the `DataGridView` tasks panel.

The click events of the `DataGridView` buttons work without a problem!

I want to perform a click on `DataGridView` button programmatically when I click another button outside of the `DataGridView`. How should I do this?

The code of the DataGridView is:

```
Private Sub dgvAnimSel_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
    Handles dgvAnimSel.CellContentClick
    Dim V As String = dgvAnimSel.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value
    If e.ColumnIndex = 3 Then
        If V = 1 Then
            If A1 = 1 Then
                'this is the uncheck state
                Me.dgvAnimSel.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.White
                Me.dgvAnimSel.CurrentCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Black
                Me.dgvAnimSel.CurrentCell.Value = "Select"
                ItemTextNew = ItemTextOr + "1"
                ItemName = ListView1.FindItemWithText(ItemTextNew, False, 0, True)
                ListView1.Items.Remove(ItemName)
                A1 = 0
            Else
                'this is the check state
                Me.dgvAnimSel.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Green
                Me.dgvAnimSel.CurrentCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.White
                Me.dgvAnimSel.CurrentCell.Value = "Selected"
                a = ListView1.Items.Add(" " + "Animation 1 ", 0)
                A1 = 1
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: *I want to change the state of a DataGridView button programmatically* Change to what state? What kind of change do you mean?

Comment: With the change state I mean to perform a click on the DataGridView button sorry my mistake! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use either of the following options:

- Calling the event handler of `CellContentClick` like a normal method by creating an instance of `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` and pass it to the event handler method.
- Or put the whole logic inside a method and call that method whenever you need, from `CellContentClick` of the `DataGridView` or `Click` of the button.

### VB.NET

**Example 1 - Perform Click for DataGridView Button Cell by calling the event handler**

To programmatically click on button in specific row, you can call the method that you created as event handler of `CellContentClick` event, using suitable [`DataGridViewCellEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) as `e` and your `DataGridView` as `sender`:

```
Private Sub AnotherButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles AnotherButton.Click
    ' zero based ColumnIndex of your button column= 3 (for example)
    ' zero based RowIndex that you want to click on its button column = 2 (for example)
    Dim arg = New DataGridViewCellEventArgs(3, 2) 
    DataGridView1_CellContentClick(DataGridView1, arg)
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, _
    e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    MessageBox.Show(e.RowIndex.ToString())
End Sub
```

**Example 2 - Putting the logic in another method and call the method when you need**

As another option you can put the logic related to click on a cell button in a method, dependent from `Cell` and `Row` objects and only pass suitable values to that method. Then you can call the method wherever you need.

```
Private Sub DoSomething(rowIndex as Integer, columnIndex as Integer)
    MessageBox.Show(rowIndex.ToString())
End Sub

Private Sub AnotherButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles AnotherButton.Click
    ' zero based ColumnIndex of your button column= 3 (for example)
    ' zero based RowIndex that you want to click on its button column = 2 (for example)
    DoSomething(2, 3) 
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, _
    e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    DoSomething(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex)
End Sub
```

### C#

**Example 1 - Perform Click for DataGridView Button Cell by calling the event handler**

To programmatically click on button in specific row, you can call the method that you created as event handler of `CellContentClick` event, using suitable [`DataGridViewCellEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) as `e` and your `DataGridView` as `sender`:

```
private void anotherButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ' zero based ColumnIndex of your button column= 3 (for example)
    ' zero based RowIndex that you want to click on its button column = 2 (for example)
    var arg = new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(3, 2); 
    dataGridView1_CellContentClick(dataGridView1, arg);
}

private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.RowIndex.ToString());
}
```

**Example 2 - Putting the logic in another method and call the method when you need**

As another option you can put the logic related to click on a cell button in a method, dependent from `Cell` and `Row` objects and only pass suitable values to that method. Then you can call the method wherever you need.

```
private void DoSomething(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(rowIndex.ToString());
}

private void anotherButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ' zero based ColumnIndex of your button column= 3 (for example)
    ' zero based RowIndex that you want to click on its button column = 2 (for example)
    DoSomething(2, 3); 
}

private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! Mr Ivan I tried what you suggested but it does not seam to work... Mr Reza, your approach works but when I run the app it displays a DataGridView Default Error Dialog with System.Exception: Selected is not a valid value for Int32... What does this mean?
Again thank you very much!

Comment: To test my answer independent from your program,arrange a simple test as I did. `MessageBox.Show(e.RowIndex.ToString())` that I forgot to use `.ToString()` Then If it worked (That will work properly) it means the solution is OK and you should apply it to your program.

Comment: @Kostas I didn't check Ivan's answer, but I think it should be useful. Also you should inform Ivan if you want to ask questions or if you need more help, by commenting below his answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate programmatically click on `DataGridViewButtonCell` instance, you can use [DataGridViewCell.AccessibilityObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.accessibilityobject(v=vs.110).aspx) property and call [DoDefaultAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.datagridviewcellaccessibleobject.dodefaultaction(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Something like this (sorry for C#, I'm sure you can translate it to VB):

```
DataGridViewButtonCell otherCell = ...;
otherCell.AccessibilityObject.DoDefaultAction();
```

Test:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Samples
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var form = new Form();
            var grid = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = form, AutoGenerateColumns = false };
            var col0 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Col0", HeaderText = "Col0", DataPropertyName = "Col0" };
            var col1 = new DataGridViewButtonColumn { Name = "Col1", HeaderText = "Col1", DataPropertyName = "Col1" };
            grid.Columns.AddRange(new DataGridViewColumn[] { col0, col1 });
            grid.CellContentClick += (sender, e) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Clicked Cell[" + e.RowIndex + "," + e.ColumnIndex + "]");
            };
            grid.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(n => new { Col0 = "Cell[" + n + ",0]", Col1 = "Cell[" + n + ",1]" }).ToList();
            var button = new Button { Dock = DockStyle.Bottom, Parent = form, Text = "Click" };
            button.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var cell = grid.CurrentRow.Cells[col1.Index];
                cell.AccessibilityObject.DoDefaultAction();
            };
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kostas It also works fine. Don't forget to add a reference to `Accessibility` assembly.

Answer (score 0):

you are encountering trouble because unlike the Button control which exposes the method:

```
public void PerformClick();
```

the DatagridView family do not expose this method.
@Microsoft : I am not proud of you!

However the DataGridView class exposes the CurrentCell property:

```
public DataGridViewCell CurrentCell { get; set; }
```

and this property triggers the event CurrentCellChanged:

```
    public event EventHandler CurrentCellChanged;
```

Hence my suggestion is that instead of putting your handler on Click, put it on CurrentCellChanged and perform the triggering by **setting the current cell**  instead of looking for a **Click()** method which does not exist inside the framework, like this:

```
DataGridViewCell currentCell = ...;
grid.CurrentCell = currentCell;
```

If you use this solution, I will be happy to know it by you voting with the button on the left.

Youtube channel:
https://youtube.com/channel/UCVww4lxZnKGx_5I4clpb52w